# singleton doesn't work for a static function

Tags: php, singleton

**Another part of the system as causing the problem, the problem has been solved**

```
public static function getParticpantsIdsWithTitles(array $proftitlecodes)
{
     //connect_mysqli is a singleton, but everytime this is called a new instance is created
    $sqlconn = connect_mysqli::get_instance();
}

//All of these method calls cause the constructor of connect_mysqli to run

Participant::getParticpantsIdsWithTitles(array(1,2,3));    
Participant::getParticpantsIdsWithTitles(array(1,2,3));
```

Is there some rule I don't know about a singleton when using it from a static function? a new mysqli_object is being created every time. (ONLY FROM static functions). It works fine from non-static functions.

```
private static $instance = FALSE;
  var  $host ;
  var  $dbUser ;
  var  $dbPass ;
  var  $dbName ;
  var  $dbConn ;
  var  $dbconnectError ;
  var  $query;
  var  $result;
  var  $row;

    function __construct () 
    {
        $this->host   = 'host' ;
        $this->dbUser = 'user' ;
        $this->dbPass = 'password' ;
        $this->dbName = 'db' ;
        $this->dbConn = new mysqli($this->host , $this->dbUser , $this->dbPass, $this->dbName )  ;

        file_put_contents("/Library/WebServer/Documents/test.txt", "CONNECT\n", FILE_APPEND);
        if ( !$this->dbConn )
        {
            trigger_error ('could not connect to server' ) ;
            $this->dbconnectError = true ;
        }
    }

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if(!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance = new connect_mysqli();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
```

Comment: [Why Singletons have no use in PHP](http://gooh.posterous.com/singletons-in-php)

Comment: Please provide a self-contained minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. The following code prints

> A new connect_mysqli was created

exactly once.

```
class foo 
{
  public static function getParticpantsIdsWithTitles(array $proftitlecodes)
  {
    $sqlconn = connect_mysqli::get_instance();
  }
}

class connect_mysqli
{
  private static $instance = FALSE;

  public function __construct()
  {
    echo "A new connect_mysqli was created\n";
  }

  public static function get_instance()
  {
    if(!self::$instance)
    {
      self::$instance = new connect_mysqli();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
{
  foo::getParticpantsIdsWithTitles(array());
}
```

Comment: getParticpantsIdsWithTitles is in its own class

Comment: @ChrisMuench Accounted for. Still no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem, but I did notice something about your singleton:

```
function __construct ()
```

This will default the `__construct()` method to `public` visibility. Generally constructors of singletons will be marked as `private` to prevent instantiation outside of the provided `get_instance()` method.

Are you sure that you're only ever using `get_instance()` and *never* doing something like `$mysqli = new connect_mysqli()`? Are you also sure you're not creating db connections from a context outside of your singleton?